# How do I get minimal polygons from vertex and edge data?

Tags: algorithm

[image]

Lets say i have all the vertexes named `e1, e2, e3, ...`  and each of them has the coodinate data in GPS

Also i have all the edge datas like `(e1, e2), (e2, e3), ...`

And i need to get all the polygons made of these vertexes and edges data.

## . They should *NOT* overlap each others

## . They should be the **Smallest**, cant be smaller any more(by removing a vertex)

Answer (score 0):

Are all your edges noncrossing? This is not clear from your question. In that case, if I understand your question correctly, you formally want to determine the regions in a planar graph.

If so, here is a possible approach (I assume that the graph is connected): For each vertex make a list of adjacent vertices in clockwise order. Pick one, choose one of its end points as start vertex. Now trace a path by following the edge and picking the next edge in the clockwise order at a vertex until you reach the start vertex. That path bounds a region. For each used edge remember the direction you have travelled along it. Repeat this process as long as you have an edge which has not been used in both directions.

Comment: yes, all my edges noncrossing. are there any exsiting algorithm to solve this type of problem? i dont think i was the first guy who need this

Comment: There are the software libraries CGAL and LEDA for computational geometric algorithms. CGAL has a package for 2D arrangements, and your planar graph problem is a special case of this, LEDA knows embedded planar graphs and has a method to obtain the regions. It seems that both internally use an algorithm similar to the one I suggested. I haven't worked with either of the packages, so I can't say which one is better suited for your need. I am not aware of any other implemntations.

Comment: How do you find the most clockwise edge to travel down next?